# k8s kubernetes fails initail test

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and am trying to learn.

I set up 2 VMs and they connect to eachother via a host-only network.

I followed these 2 guides:

[How to Install Kubernetes Cluster on Debian 11 with Kubeadm](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-cluster-on-debian/)

[Deploy Kubernetes Cluster on Debian 11 with Containerd](https://www.hostafrica.ng/blog/servers/kubernetes-cluster-debian-11-containerd/)

Everything seems to go well until I get to "9) Test Kubernetes Cluster Installation"

```
(Master)$ kubectl create deployment nginx-app --image=nginx --replicas 2
deployment.apps/nginx-app created
```

```
(Master)$ kubectl expose deployment nginx-app --name=nginx-web-svc --type NodePort --port 80 --target-port 80
service/nginx-web-svc exposed
```

```
(Master)$ kubectl describe svc nginx-web-svc
Name:                     nginx-web-svc
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=nginx-app
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=nginx-app
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.96.22.154
IPs:                      10.96.22.154
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30315/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Note: the Endpoints: < none > does not match the expected output in the walkthrough.  it has `Endpoints:  172.16.126.1:80, 172.16.194.65:80`

and when I try and access the exposed port...

```
(Master)$ curl http://k-worker-01:30315
curl: (7) Failed to connect to k-worker-01 port 30315: Connection refused
```

Note: in my vm setup I have 2 network adapters

1. attached to NAT
2. attached to Host-only Adapter

I can ping in both directions

```
$ ping -c4 k-worker-01
```

and

```
$ ping -c4 k-master
```

I'm not sure what to try next.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Missing `Endpoints` is caused by there being no Pods in `Ready` that match `app=nginx-app`; you'll want to start by [editing your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1116089/edit) to include `kubectl get -o yaml svc/nginx-web-svc` and `kubectl get -o yaml po -l app=nginx-app` since that cute `kubectl expose` and `kubectl run` stuff is really designed only to make people ask questions, and not for good outcomes